# JSON encode with php is generating array

Tags: php, json

I need to generate an encoded JSON string from an array. However when I simply unset an item from the array the structure of the entire string gets very different.

Take as example this code:

```
$temp1 = array();

$temp1[] = array("x" => "aaa", "y" => "bbb");
$temp1[] = array("x" => "ccc", "y" => "ddd");
$temp1[] = array("x" => "eee", "y" => "fff");

$encoded = json_encode($temp1);

echo $encoded;
```

It will output:

`[{"x":"aaa","y":"bbb"},{"x":"ccc","y":"ddd"},{"x":"eee","y":"fff"}]`

Of course, that's what I expect! Now just take a look at this very similar code below:

```
$temp1 = array();

$temp1[] = array("x" => "aaa", "y" => "bbb");
$temp1[] = array("x" => "ccc", "y" => "ddd");
$temp1[] = array("x" => "eee", "y" => "fff");

unset($temp1[0]);

$encoded = json_encode($temp1);

echo $encoded;
```

It will output

`"{"1":{"x":"ccc","y":"ddd"},"2":{"x":"eee","y":"fff"}}"`

How can I make the second code work as the first (which in my mind is the expected result, since the act of removing and element from the array should not affect the structure of the output encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unset** will keep indexes untouched, so, after use unset, you can "recalculate" the data using **array_values**:

```
<?php
$temp1 = array();

$temp1[] = array("x" => "aaa", "y" => "bbb");
$temp1[] = array("x" => "ccc", "y" => "ddd");
$temp1[] = array("x" => "eee", "y" => "fff");

unset($temp1[0]);
$temp1 = array_values($temp1);
$encoded = json_encode($temp1);

echo $encoded;
// will output the expected result:[{"x":"ccc","y":"ddd"},{"x":"eee","y":"fff"}]
?>
```

Comment: array_values is exactly what I should have been using! It worked perfecty, tahsnk!

Answer (score 0):

```
        $temp1 = array();
        $temp1[] = array("x" => "aaa", "y" => "bbb");
        $temp1[] = array("x" => "ccc", "y" => "ddd");
        $temp1[] = array("x" => "eee", "y" => "fff");

        array_splice($temp1,0,1);

        $encoded = json_encode($temp1);
        echo $encoded;
```

Comment: Your code works but the array_values is a more general and better approach. Thanks anyway, your solution works fine :)